# PHP How to allow mysql to connect from remote server

Tags: php, mysql, database, server

I have 2 VPS running on centos 7.
VPS #1: 192.164.64.76
VPS #2: 192.164.64.19

ON VPS #2 I have a database named DBASE. I need to connect to it from remote server(VPS #1). I have tried everything and still MySQL does not allow me to connect.  I need a step by step guide to show me how to solve my issue.
This is my PHP code(I put it on VPS #1)

```
<?php 
    DEFINE ('DB_USER_1', 'remoteuser');
    DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD_1', 'dsdafdf4323fe');
    DEFINE ('DB_HOST_1', '192.164.64.19');
    DEFINE ('DB_NAME_1', 'dbase');

    $pol1 = @mysql_connect (DB_HOST_1, DB_USER_1, DB_PASSWORD_1)
OR die ('Nie mogłem się połączyć: ' . mysql_error() );
    @mysql_select_db (DB_NAME_1) OR die ('Nie mogłem wybrać bazy danych: ' . mysql_error() );
?>
```

Gives me error:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.164.64.19' (13)

Comment: stop using deprecated+removed `mysql_*` library. switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Also don't use error-skipping `@`. it's make your job even harder as a programmer.

Comment: Im not web-dev, im not very familiar with PHP, this is just part of code. Im only looking on guide how to setup servers correctly for my purposes.

Comment: remove your details man. you can get a big problem if some-one got intrested in using your credentials. don't provide any live credentials. remove it right now

Comment: Marcin, ports open in firewalls? The MySQL user has privileges...`remoteuser@192%`?  There are so many things it could be. Might need you to narrow it down.

Comment: Hmm all credentials are faked of course

Comment: Did you set a remote access on the host server?

Comment: From the console on the same machine, try `mysql -h 192.164.64.19 -u remoteuser -p dbase` to see if you can connect using the MySQL client. I wonder whether (a) you have a local firewall in the way, (b) you have a remote firewall in the way, or (c) the remote MySQL server is only listening on `localhost`.

Comment: Fact that its error code 13? I'd maybe start with a look at selinux. Suggests directory permission issue. Can you even connect locally? Would maybe start with that.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
DEFINE ('DB_USER_1', 'remoteuser');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD_1', 'dsdafdf4323fe');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST_1', '192.164.64.19');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME_1', 'dbase');

$pol1 = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST_1, DB_USER_1, DB_PASSWORD_1)
OR die ('Nie mogłem się połączyć: ' . mysql_error() );
mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME_1) OR die ('Nie mogłem wybrać bazy danych: ' . mysql_error() );
```

Comment: check the host you're pointing to has the same network with you